# Can we use wait() method on constructors? Java

Tags: java, concurrency, constructor, wait

Can we use wait() method on constructors?
I have a constructor method in which i call some other initializers methods and after the methods for gui. But it seams that it loads gui before the first methods. So it gives errors to objects that haven't been initialized. I tried to use wait() before gui's calling but there is an IllegalMonitorStateException error as it's not in a synchronized block.

Trying to do sth like that:

```
dice = new Dice();
this.generateBoard();
this.generateCells();

this.wait(200,100);   //otherwise??
//GUI
board = new GUI(this);
```

Comment: BTW: using wait(200,100) is the same as wait(200). The wait(m,n) is pretty pointless IMHO.

Comment: yeah you are right Peter,i just tested it.thnx for the note

Comment: What GUI API are you trying to multithread? Do you mean `Thread.sleep` rather than `wait`?

Comment: What's the purpose of putting `this` in front of method invocations?

Comment: @Steve Kuo. Fixed thanx.just due to the quickness.

Answer (score 6):

As you noted, you should call `wait()` within a `synchronized` block. And synchronizing by default means you lock on `this`, thus in effect publishing the object before it is fully constructed - a **very bad** idea.

But - as @Jon pointed out - even if you did explicitly lock on a different object than `this`, you still needed to publish `this` prematurely to another thread in order for `wait()` to make any sense (otherwise who could ever `notify()` it?). So this scheme smells.

A better alternative would be using a static factory method to construct the object fully, *then* publish it safely:

```
class MyClass {
  private MyClass() {
    ...
  }
  public static MyClass createAndPublish() {
    MyClass theInstance = new MyClass();
    // here you can already synchronize on theInstance, call wait() etc.
    return theInstance;
  }
}
```

Notice that the constructor is declared `private` to ensure that the only way to create new instances is via `createAndPublish()`:

```
MyClass newInstance = MyClass.createAndPublish();
```

Comment: static factory method? could u pls describe it a little more. i havent ever listened about that. im new in java.

Comment: so i use this one for example on my constructor?

Comment: @FILIaS, no, *instead* of the constructor. Check out my extended example.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you *can* use `wait` within a constructor - you'd just have to synchronize on "this" within the constructor:

```
// I'm not actually recommending this...
synchronized (this) {
    this.wait(...);
}
```

However, it's not clear what would `notify` the reference, unless you'd leaked "this" in the constructor to something which was using it in another thread.

It's not at all clear how this is failing to start with to be honest - although I suspect it's to do with leaking "this" at the end of the constructor. Do your initialization methods start extra threads to do their work? It seems to me that you should find out *exactly* what's going on before you try to fix it - and just pausing for some time seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Presumably you mean `notify` rather than `pulse` - the question is tagged Java.

Comment: im trying to find what;s going on but from the first sight it seemed to me that object havent been initialized before gui. so i tried to pause it just to see.

Comment: to tell the truth because i had never before used it. and wait() seemed a bit more understandable :/

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use wait() method on constructors?

Not really, as others have pointed out.

But you can split your constructor code into two parts.  Do the part that can safely be done before your GUI is created in the constructor.  Do the part that has to wait for the GUI to be created in an `initialize`() method, that can be called after the GUI creation.

Comment: "Do the part that has to wait for the GUI to be created in an initialize() method, that can be called after the GUI creation"... after GUI creation???why after?